# Reproducir video al entrar a la web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy metido en una web donde queremos introducir un video que se reproduzca al entrar a la web y una vez que se haya visto completo que permita ver e interactuar con la web.

Tipo el gif de carga de la web, pero con un video que tienes que ver completo.

¿Alguien tiene ideas de cómo puedo integrarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Como comentan en este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691821/how-can-i-force-a-user-to-view-a-video-before-entering-website

Lo que podés hacer siempre y cuando el video esté en youtube es usar la API de Youtube para reproducirlo:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            alert('done');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Cuando event.data es 0 (`event.data === 0`) significa que el video terminó y podés redireccionar a donde quieras.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo, evita responder preguntas mal formuladas, ya que las mismas terminan cerradas y tu contribución en el sitio se pierde. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos